SwiftData ValueTransformer to store a collection of `.transformable(by:` objects?
I've written a custom ValueTransformer to store an object type that does not receive automatic compliance for SwiftData:

How to use SwiftData ValueTransformer with a custom NSMeasurement Dimension Unit?

I now want to store collections of that same type as variables on a SwiftData model:
@Model
class TestModel {
    // Works after adding custom MeasurementTransformer
    @Attribute(.transformable(by: MeasurementTransformer.self)) let measurement: NSMeasurement

    // Not working
    let measurementArray: [NSMeasurement]
    let measurementDict: [String: NSMeasurement]
    
    init(measurement: NSMeasurement, measurementArray: [NSMeasurement], measurementDict: [String : NSMeasurement]) {
        self.measurement = measurement
        self.measurementArray = measurementArray
        self.measurementDict = measurementDict
    }
}

This throws errors for the Array and Dictionary:

Referencing instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' on 'Array' requires that 'NSMeasurement' conform to 'PersistentModel'
Referencing instance method 'getValue(forKey:)' on 'Array' requires that 'NSMeasurement' conform to 'PersistentModel'

Is there any special syntax for @Attribute(.transformable(by: (or any other way) to share code between the single-object transformer and a transformer for when that type is packed into an array or dictionary? Or do I need to write entirely new ValueTransformers for every situation where that type appears in a collection?

Then, when I actually do try to add a ValueTransformer for the collections, there seem to be issues with the collections implementing NSCoding or casting to AnyClass. Presumably because Swift collections are struct not class? Is there an alternative to ValueTransformer for collections?
final class MeasurementArrayTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "MeasurementArrayTransformer")

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let measurements = value as? [NSMeasurement] else { return nil }
        do { return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: measurements, requiringSecureCoding: true) } catch { debugPrint(error); return nil }
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
        do { return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [NSMeasurement].self, from: data) } catch { debugPrint(error); return nil }
        // ERROR: Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[NSMeasurement]' conform to 'NSCoding'
    }
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool { true }
    
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        [NSMeasurement].self
        // ERROR: Cannot convert return expression of type '[NSMeasurement].Type' to return type 'AnyClass' (aka 'any AnyObject.Type')
    }
}


You can keep the property's type as a Swift Array in the Model class, but then bridge to NSArray in the ValueTransformer when storing it in SwiftData / Core Data:
@Attribute(.transformable(by: MeasurementArrayTransformer.self)) let measurementArray: [NSMeasurement]

Use NSArray.self for the ValueTransformer's transformedValueClass and cast to/from NSArray:
final class MeasurementArrayTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "MeasurementArrayTransformer")

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let measurements = value as? [NSMeasurement] else { return nil }
        let nsArray = measurements as NSArray
        do {
            return try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: nsArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error);
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
        do {
            let nsArrayAny = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSMeasurement.self], from: data)
            guard let measurements = nsArrayAny as? [NSMeasurement] else { return nil }
            return measurements
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error);
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool { true }
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass { NSArray.self }
}

